# finding duplicates in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that looks like the following:

```
            {value: 20, color: 'F88C00'},
            {value: 40, color: 'D8605F'},
            {value: 20, color: '72C380'},
            {value: 20, color: '2C7282'},
            {value: 20, color: '72C380'}
```

I want to use javascript/jquery to loop through them to check if there are any duplicates in the color column, and if there are duplicates, here '72C380' occurs twice. Then there should be only one entry but their values should be summed.

Desired Output:

```
            {value: 20, color: 'F88C00'},
            {value: 40, color: 'D8605F'},
            **{value: 40, color: '72C380'},**
            {value: 20, color: '2C7282'}
```

I know how to do that in python, but not JS

Comment: Do you want to delete it?

Comment: I want to delete the duplicate ones but add upp the values

Answer (score 8):

You can use a temp map like this

```
var array = [{
    value: 20,
    color: 'F88C00'
}, {
    value: 40,
    color: 'D8605F'
}, {
    value: 20,
    color: '72C380'
}, {
    value: 20,
    color: '2C7282'
}, {
    value: 20,
    color: '72C380'
}];

var op = [],
    map = {}, it, item;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    it = array[i];
    item = map[it.color];
    if (item) {
        item.value += it.value;
    } else {
        map[it.color] = item = {
            value: it.value,
            color: it.color
        };
        op.push(item);
    }
}
console.log(op)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Tamm/)

Answer (score 0):

console it ...

```
var collection = [{value: 20, color: 'F88C00'},
            {value: 40, color: 'D8605F'},
            {value: 20, color: '72C380'},
            {value: 20, color: '2C7282'},
            {value: 20, color: '72C380'}];


var colors = [];
var result = collection;
$.each(result, function(i, item){ 
  if(colors.indexOf(item.color)!= -1){ 
      $.each(result,function(f, find){
        if(find.color == item.color){
          result[f].value += item.value;
        }
      })
      delete result[i];
  }else{
     colors.push(item.color);  
  } 
})
var colors = [];
console.log(result);
```